# How do we get Vets 100 Compliance Documentation

Tags: usa

We are pursing a VA construction project and one of the required pieces of information is Vets 100 Compliance documentation.  How do we go about getting said documentation ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the U.S. Department of Labor Veterans' Employment and Training service (VETS) VETS-100 form is part of the [VETS-4212 compliance program](http://www.dol.gov/vets/vets4212.htm).

The contact email is VETS4212-customersupport@dol.gov